# codeigniter form not submitting data

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have tried everything I can think of but whenever I click submit the form passes on a null value, I dont know if it is the problem with the form or the controller or even the view. I changed this->input->post to posted data and i get an error of undefined variable posted data, please help.

Controller:

```
 public function addmenu(){

    $this->load->model('organizer_model');

    $data = array(
                'menu_name' => $this->input->post('menu name'), 
                'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
                'email' => $this->session->userdata('email')

            );

            if($this->organizer_model->insertmenu($data)) {

    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Your menu has been added');
    redirect('/menu/index', 'refresh');

    } else {

    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Your menu was not added, please try again');
    redirect('/menu/index', 'refresh');
    }
```

View:

```
              <form action="<?php echo site_url('Organizer/addmenu'); ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal no-margin">

                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="menuname">
                     Menu Name
                    </label>
                    <div class="controls controls-row">
                      <input class="span3" name="data[menuname]" type="text" placeholder="Enter menu Name">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="price">
                      Price
                    </label>
                    <div class="controls controls-row">
                      <input class="span3" name="data[price]" type="text" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-actions no-margin">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">
                      Add menu
                    </button>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </form>
```

Model:

```
   public function insertmenu($data) {

    $condition = "email = '" . $data['email'] . "'";
    $this->db->select('organizer_id');
    $this->db->from('organizer');
    $this->db->where($condition);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){

        array_pop($data); //will remove email from data

        $row = $query->row();
        $data['organizer_id'] = $row->organizer_id;

        $this->db->insert('menu', $data);
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: iirc, this code: `$this->input->post('price')` expects this `<input name="price">`

Comment: yes, isnt that is what is already going on?

Comment: you have `name="data[price]"`

Comment: okay so i changed it to price but it is still entering data into the db, why is that?

Comment: title says `CI form does not submitting data` does that mean you did not do any mistake?Improve your question.debugging help type question is off-topic at SO.You should write the full error message,and the error message also the answer what mistake you did.

Answer (score 2):

I notice same question here [codeigniter- insert data into db not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763055/codeigniter-insert-data-into-db-not-working)

Checks

Make sure you load your form helper and url helper.

Make sure you use form validation when submitting form in codeigniter on controller.

---

From this php user guide here http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Example on your input would be like **person[0][first_name]**

```
<form action="" method="">
    <input type="text" name="data_posts[0][menu_name]" placeholder="Enter menu Name">
    <input type="text" name="data_posts[0][price]"  placeholder="">
</form>
```

**Model**

```
<?php

class Model_something extends CI_Model {

public function add_menu() {
    $data_posts = $this->input->post('data_posts');

    foreach ($data_posts as $data_post) {
        $data = array(
            'email' => $this->session->userdata('email'),
            'menu_name' => $data_post['menu_name'],
            'price' => $data_post['price']
        );

        $this->db->insert('tablename', $data);
    }
}

}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php 

class Add_menu extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $data_posts = $this->input->post('data_posts');

        foreach ($data_posts as $data_post) {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('data_posts['.$data_post.'][menu_name]', 'Menu Name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('data_posts['.$data_post.'][price]', 'Price', 'required');
        }

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('some_view');
        } else {
            $this->load->model('model_something');
            $this->model_something->add_menu();
            redirect('to_success_page');
        }
    }
}
```

**You could also check if has been inserted by using callback function**

Codeigniter 3 user guide form validation http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Codeigniter 2 user guide form validation http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/form_validation.html

Also you should upgrade to the new bootstrap I see your using old version.